# Heroku -- Push new content to a heroku app created from a different machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3, setup-deployment

Our team is working on an app. We have a SVN based app. We also pushed the app to heroku. The other day the app was pushed by one member of the team, and after a couple of days of work and making some updations other member wants to push his data on heroku in the same repo from another machine. How can this be done?

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Actually what I want to know is how do I initialize the already present repo on my Heroku command. Because when I do `heroku info` I get this `No app specified. Run this command from app folder or set it adding --app <app name>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Git to push applications to Heroku. If your source control of choice is Subversion, then you can use `git-svn` to deal with a Subversion repository using Git, including pushing to Heroku.

You need to add a git remote to the Heroku Git URL. You can find this URL in your Heroku account at heroku.com.

```
# stuff about setting up git-svn
$ git remote add heroku #{heroku_git_url}
$ git push heroku master
```

As another commenter mentioned, you will also need to manage SSH keys. The user doing the pushing will need to have an SSH private key (you can look up `ssh-keygen`) and will need to have the SSH public key uploaded to Heroku (`heroku ssh` subcommand).

Answer (score 0):

So if your app is deployed and you already have a working copy. And you need to push changes.

You only want the repo with no content.

```
git clone --no-checkout git@heroku.com:<your-app-name>
```

That will clone the repo into a directory named your-app-name, and in that directory will be the repo you want. Move that .git file next to your .svn file.

```
mv <your-app-name>/.git ~/Code/<your-working-copy>
rm -rf <you-app-name>
```

You can rename the origin remote to heroku if you want. Otherwise just

```
git commit -am "Deploying v1.2"
git push
```